# Look inside to answer this

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

> Qwb'kr
>   kkuau;    ekx  kbwq   .

I'll say that what is important is not what you read.

Hint 1:

> If you have a problem with my riddle edit it. If you dislike it, maybe you should try solving it.

Hint 2:

> All that you need is included inside, but from the outside it won't make enough sense

Hint 3:

> A one time pad should be thrown away.

Answer to prove the hold reason wrong:

> If you click edit you see a hint that says look at the white space. The white space says in morse code "this." I leave the hints to be solved later.

Comment: Puzzles that are just a ["solve this code!"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do/) are generally not fun to solve, given that there are too many possibilities and it's basically impossible to solve without more information. Remember, the puzzle is probably harder than you think it is! Perhaps instead of waiting, you should just add the hints as is.

Comment: The core riddle you have here isn't bad, but you needed to clue it better.  The title "Decode this cipher" is practically asking for a hold since it looks nearly identical to the example of a "solve this code" puzzle.  Instead it would be better to use titles and text that give hints like "The code of empty space" or "What isn't said is understanding" to clue that white space is the entry point for this riddle.

Comment: @Barker is it better now with the changed title and added enigmaty?

Comment: Better.  Also red herrings are generally discouraged, so it might be cool if the text between the white space was a clue as well.  For example it could be rot13 for "You're looking in the wrong place" or something like that.  With those changes I'd vote to reopen (but I don't have the rep). Opening a closed question is hard, so you might be better off making a new question with the better title and clues and the removal of the red herring.

Comment: @Barker Gur grkgf npghnyyl vf hfrf n bar-gvzr cnq jurer gur xrl vf gur zrffntr onpxjneqf.

Comment: I would go simpler than that.  Even with your message, I was unable to figure out exactly how to decrypt it and there is no cluing to hint that is what you should do.  Since the text should be more of a hidden clue, it should be easily decryptable using one of the first things people try.  Remember, you riddles will always look more obvious to you since you are the one who wrote them.

Comment: If this question were open, I'd write the answer. rot13(Vg vf gur cuenfr "Lbh'er jebat; abg guvf" rapvcurerq jvgu n Ivtrarer pvcure hfvat gur fnzr cuenfr jevggra onpxjneqf nf n xrl.) I got here by assuming the first word.

Answer (score 2):

Very partial answer:

> If you go to edit, you see that there is a suspicious amount of spaces between words as well as a comment "look at the white space":
>  Qwb'kr [RETURN][RETURN] kkuau;[4 SPACES] ekx [2 SPACES] kbwq [3 SPACES].
>  I have no idea where to go from here though.